# find first matches character in regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-greedy, regular-language

i have a string that i want to find "a" character and first "c" character and replace with "*" character, but regular expression find all "a" and "c" character i don't know how do it.

here my code:

```
var pattern=/[a][c]/g; //here my pattern
var str1="aaaaaaaaaabbbbbbaaaaaaaaaabbbccccccccccbbbbbbbbccc";
var rep=str1.replace(pattern,"*");
$("p").html(rep);
```

Comment: please add the wanted result.

Comment: Just remove "g" in the end. "g" mean "global search"

Comment: remove global `/g` flag from regex, use `str1.replace('a', '*').replace('c', '*')`

Comment: @AZ_ i want replace both characters "c" and "a" when i removed global just replace "a" character

Comment: you will have to use `.replace` twice.

Answer (score 0):

You need two replacements, because a single one replaces either `a` or `c`, depending on the first occurence in the string.

```js
var string = "aaaaaaaaaabbbbbbaaaaaaaaaabbbccccccccccbbbbbbbbccc",
    result = string
        .replace(/a/, '*')
        .replace(/c/, '*');

console.log(result);
```

An approach with a single replace and a closure over a hash table.

```js
var string = "aaaaaaaaaabbbbbbaaaaaaaaaabbbccccccccccbbbbbbbbccc",
    result = string.replace(/[ac]/g, (h => c => h[c] ? c : (h[c] = '*'))({}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use capture groups for all a or c sequences but the 1st, and replace them with '*$1' ($1 is the [replacement pattern](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter) for the capture group):

```js
const str = `aaaaaaaaaabbbbbbaaaaaaaaaabbbccccccccccbbbbbbbbccc`;

const result = str.replace(/[ac]([ac]+)/g, '*$1');

console.log(result);
```